# How to make an installer package where you have multiple projects and different outputs?

Tags: c#, windows-installer, setup-project, program-entry-point, setup-deployment

I have three applications, App1, App2, and App3. App3 is the main application that needs to be finally installed on the user's computer. It should go like this:

When the setup starts, it should run App1, which does some authentications, like checking the Username and computer name of the client's computer. If it fails then stop the installation and delete the whole installation file. If it passes the authentication then jump to the App2, which is security check 2, and that window will ask for a timeline, which we have provided to our users via email. If it passes that then install the main application.

Right now, I have made the setup project for the Main App [App3], whereas I have separate projects of App1 and App2. I want to incorporate all these files into one solution and form only one MSI file. I added App1 and App2 as existing projects, but when I setup the project startup to App1 then that's the only application that executes. Why?

Comment: Be aware that Windows Installer Projects (.vdproj) are not available in VS2012. If you're looking for forward compatibility, consider moving to WiX. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2011/03/17/visual-studio-setup-projects-vdproj-will-not-ship-with-future-versions-of-vs.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went out and found so many different options, but the most reasonable and easy approach with lots of capabilities is [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/). I accomplished the task using the Advanced Installer. I would definitely recommend it.

Comment: Be *extremely* careful about writing such 'glowing' reviews of a product as an answer here; it tends to look like spam, which gets nuked from high orbit very quickly around here. Looking at your whole history, I know you aren't affiliated with Advanced Installer, but that's not actually a requirement to be seen as 'spamming', anyway.

Comment: @AndrewBarber, I don't think so I am writing any glowing reviews. I just wanted to tell the community that thats the easier approach I found. And I don't have any affiliations with them.

Comment: Your post reads *exactly* like the spam posts that we see every day. I only know you aren't affiliated with them because I took the time to view your whole history. Spammers try to make their posts look like they are written by "fans" of the product, instead of the people behind it; so in actuality, it doesn't matter in the long-term if you are affiliated with it or not: If you promote the product *too much*, and *too vocally*, you could begin to *look like* a spammer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Any setup authoring tool supports this. You can find a list here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

For MSI-based installers you can execute your applications using [custom actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368066%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

You can write a batch file that runs the three separate EXEs one by one. The thing to keep in mind is that it won't be one MSI packaging 3 separate EXEs but 1 batch file and 3 EXEs.